# Is it possible to multiple a BigInteger by a Double in Java?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a very large number (*number1*) stored as a `BigInteger`, and a `double` (number2). I plan to multiply *number1* and *number2*, and store the result as a double.

Using the `multiply()` method has not helped me achieve this. What is the way forward?

Comment: Your question lacks some vital information. First being, what does "has not helped me" mean?

Comment: *"I plan to multiply number1 and number2, and store the result as a double."*  Why?  Trying to crack some unproven mathematical principle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably `big.doubleValue() * myDouble`.

This won't be particularly fast, unfortunately, since `BigInteger.doubleValue()` has a notably slow implementation.  (It might be faster in the future...perhaps if Oracle applies my [patch](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/show_bug.cgi?id=100222).)

Alternately, you can round a `double` directly to a `BigInteger` using [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`DoubleMath.roundToBigInteger(double, RoundingMode)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.html#roundToBigInteger%28double,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29).

Comment: Using the `doubleValue()` worked. Javadoc says that this method returns the BigInteger as a double. But how is this the case? The value of the BigInteger is so large, how can it fit within the scope of a double?

Comment: Doubles can hold values up to 2^1024, or about 2 * 10^308, if I remember correctly.  It only has limited _precision_ in storing those values, though.

Comment: dasblinkenlight's `BigDecimal` answer is far better than this answer as there no loss is precision

Comment: I frankly agree.  I'm not sure why that answer wasn't accepted instead of mine.

Answer (score 19):

In order to preserve the arbitrary precision as long as possible, do the multiplication in `BigDecimal`, and then convert the result to `double`, like this:

```
BigDecimal tmp = new BigDecimal(myBigInteger);
tmp = tmp.multiply(new BigDecimal(myDouble));
double res = tmp.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `.doubleValue()` on the BigInteger, and multiply them as doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Why is `BigInteger#multiply()` not helpful? There are really only two reasonable answers:

```
BigInteger a = /* whatever */;
double b = /* whatever */

// either
double result = a.multiply(new BigInteger(b)).doubleValue();
// or
double result = a.doubleValue() * b;
```

Comment: *"There are really only two reasonable answers"* - apart from the other reasonable answers :-)